# Use Dispatcher servlet for interceptor call only for selective URL

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc

I am having a controller class  with two types of methods. first type must execute its body as soon as URL is hit suppose "http://localhost:8080/SpringAOP1/welcome/two/aa". Here SpringAOP1 is my project,welcome is the controller class name(Which is set with annotation) and two is the function name with parameter "aa".
The Second type of function needs to be pre-handled by a interceptor.So when URL is hit suppose "http://localhost:8080/SpringAOP1/welcome/intercep/six/aa" the interceptor must be called. Here i am passing the "intercep" parameter with all those functions of second type which needs interceptor call.

Controller class:-

---

```
@Controlle
 @RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printWelcome1(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World 1");
    return "hello";

}
@RequestMapping( value="two/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String printWelcome2(@PathVariable String name,ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World 2");
    model.addAttribute("value", name);
    return "hello";

}

@RequestMapping( value="intercep/six/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String printWelcome6(@PathVariable String name,ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World 6");
    model.addAttribute("value", name);
    return "hello";

}
```

### `

### Dispatcher servlet

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

<bean name="HijackBeforeMethod" class="com.mkyong.common.controller.HijackBeforeMethod"/>
 <mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/intercep/*"/>
    <bean id="HijackBeforeMethod" class="com.mkyong.common.controller.HijackBeforeMethod" />
</mvc:interceptor>
 </mvc:interceptors>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

HijackBeforeMethod

### (This is the interceptor Class which is called)

```
 public class HijackBeforeMethod extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
public Boolean comp(String u,String p)
{
    Map mMap = new HashMap();
    mMap.put("aa", "bb");
    mMap.put("mm", "nn");
    mMap.put("xx", "yy");


    Iterator iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();
    String k,v;
    Boolean flg=false;
    while (iter.hasNext())
    {
        Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        if(mEntry.getKey().equals(u) && mEntry.getValue().equals(p))
          flg=true;
    }
    return flg;
}


public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
    String u="aa";
    String p="bb";



    //System.out.println(" The username is--> "+u+"  and pass is --> "+p);
    Boolean ch=comp(u,p);
            if(ch)
              {
                if(httpServletRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("get")){
                    String uri = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
                    System.out.println("The method is GET :: "+ uri);
                }

            else
              {
                return false;   
               }

    }


}
```

Please help me finding this. I am in greate trouble..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebRequestInterceptor interface instead of HandlerInterceptorAdapter.
The following code segment is working fine for me.

```
public class FlashInterceptor implements WebRequestInterceptor {
    private Flash flash;

    @Autowired
    public void setFlash(Flash flash) {
            this.flash = flash;
    }

    @Override
    public void preHandle(WebRequest request) throws Exception {
            final Map<String, Object> messages = flash.getMessages();
            if (messages.containsKey("flash_info")) {
                    request.setAttribute("flash_info", messages.get("flash_info"),
                                    RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
                    request.setAttribute("flash_info_params",
                                    messages.get("flash_info_params"),
                                    RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
            }
            if (messages.containsKey("flash_error")) {
                    request.setAttribute("flash_error", messages.get("flash_error"),
                                    RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
                    request.setAttribute("flash_error_params",
                                    messages.get("flash_error_params"),
                                    RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
            }
            if (messages.containsKey("flash_success")) {
                    request.setAttribute("flash_success",
                                    messages.get("flash_success"),
                                    RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
                    request.setAttribute("flash_success_params",
                                    messages.get("flash_success_params"),
                                    RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
            }
            flash.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(WebRequest request, ModelMap model) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(WebRequest request, Exception ex)
                    throws Exception {
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and a good response.But my problem is little bit different.I don't want to enter into the interceptor if required url pattern is not hit,as mentioned above.If unspecified url is hit I just need to go back to the controller class from where I started i.e, the function calling controller.If the keyword is found in the URL then I want to redirect to the Interceptor.